# WordPress - Display post meta_id inside onclick event

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using a plugin that opens a popup preview of a WordPress post when you click on its title from the home page blogroll. It does this through an onclick event. Currently in my content.php I have only been able to display the same post when you click on any posts as its using one posts specific ID like so.

```
onclick="return ppp_open('this-where-the-id-goes', 'none', 640, 480, 160);"
```

this is what's in the plugin file.

```
onclick="return ppp_open(\''.$meta['id'].'\', \''.$meta['template'].'\', '.$meta['width'].', '.$meta['height'].', '.($meta['template'] == 'top' ? $meta['image_height'] : $meta['image_width']).');"
```

So what I need to do is generate each posts meta ID inside the onlick event.

My php is limited but when I used  `<?php the_meta(); ?>` it showed a list of eachs posts meta data and ppp_id contained the id I need to generate for each post inside the onclick event

- ppp_version: 1.29
- **ppp_id: cleae7Nv9Sp4UzVu - THIS IS WHAT I NEED**
- ppp_template: none
- ppp_width: 640
- ppp_height: 480
- ppp_image_height:160
- ppp_image_width: 160
- ppp_title_type: default
- ppp_title:
- ppp_text_type: default
- ppp_text:
- ppp_image_type: default
- ppp_image:

thought it could be something like `<?php the_meta('ppp_id'); ?>` but this didn't work, as I said I have very limited knowledge.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What you get after: var_dump($meta); ?

Answer (score 0):

So I've figuerd it out I read through the get get_post_meta codex and found the solution! this is what worked

```
<?php echo(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ppp_id', true)); ?>
```

Comment: i believe it should be this: <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ppp_id', true); ?>